# Probably easy, jet I can't get it to work (Mediaplayer)

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm making a soundboard app and I can't figure out how to get my sound playing. This is my MainActivity.java. I want it to play a different sound on each button. Also it has to automaticly stop playing the previous sounds. (I just began developing for android, so I'm not that good as you might have noticed).

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:

Here is the new version of my java:

```
    package com.mega.soundboard;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();


    int[] buttonIds = {R.id.btn1_1,R.id.btn1_2,R.id.btn1_3,R.id.btn1_4,R.id.btn1_5,R.id.btn1_6,R.id.btn1_7,R.id.btn1_8,R.id.btn1_9,R.id.btn1_10,R.id.btn1_11,R.id.btn1_12,R.id.btn1_13,R.id.btn1_14};
    int[] soundIds = {R.raw.sound01, R.raw.sound02, R.raw.sound03, R.raw.sound04, R.raw.sound05, R.raw.sound06, R.raw.sound07, R.raw.sound08, R.raw.sound09, R.raw.sound10, R.raw.sound11, R.raw.sound12, R.raw.sound13, R.raw.sound14, R.raw.sound15, R.raw.sound16};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
        //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
        //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
        for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
            if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = v.getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    try {
                        player.reset();
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                        player.prepare();
                        player.start();
                        afd.close();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the new log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mega.soundboard/com.mega.soundboard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
at com.mega.soundboard.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
... 11 more
Sending signal. PID: 16842 SIG: 9
```

Here is my layout file: (it's pretty basic)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#232b09">

<RelativeLayout

  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


  <!--  Screen Design for VIDEOS -->
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:text="@string/button1.1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.2"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.1"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.3"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.3"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.2"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.4"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.4"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.3"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.5"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.5"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.4"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.6"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.6"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.5"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.7"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.7"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.6"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.8"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.8"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.7"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.9"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.9"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.8"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />      
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.10"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.10"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.9"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />          
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.11"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.11"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.10"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />  

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.12"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.12"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.11"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />      
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.13"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.13"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.12"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />          
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn1.14"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:text="@string/button1.14"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#44511c" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.13"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />                  
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you don't use your res object anyway, you might as well just delete it the code will have the same effect, unless you're using it in other parts that are not showing ..

Comment: This log error doesn't match with the code, please test again

Comment: I've just changed your code, unisntall your apk from the device and then run with the new code

Comment: Oops, I also just changed the code, because someone asked for an update. Could you post it again?

Comment: Alright. I've changed it to your code. The app is starting now, thank you! Though the buttons don't work properly. There even isn't a log out when tapping them. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: post your layout xml file activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your **Resource** object allocation to your `onCreate` method. before that your activity's **Context** is not set yet through ContextWrapper object.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
res = getResouces();
}
```

Also add for each button you have in the layout file onClick attribute to call the `onClick` function in your activity:

```
   <Button
  android:id="@+id/btn1.11"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/button1.11"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:background="#44511c" 
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/btn1.10"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:onClick="onClick"
/>
```

Comment: Alright, edited like you told me (I think). Jet I have another error. I edited my question with the changed java and a new log. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
```

Your `res` is `null` when you are tring to access it you are getting `NullPointerException`

```
Resources res = getResources();
```

You should get the resources inside of `onCreate()` because `getResources()` needs `context.`

Comment: If I place my resources beneath the oncreate() I get the same error. By placing it below the onClick, the buttons won't work.

Comment: Declare it as a field and then initialize it in the onCreate as `Mr.me` shown

Comment: Alright, edited like Mr.Me told me (I think). Jet I have another error. I edited my question with the changed java and a new log. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Wannabe Declaring field in the sense `Resources res;` is there any other Exceptin?

Comment: @Wannabe Also Change this `getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);`  to `v.getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);`

Comment: @Wannabe You haven't changed this `Resources res = getResources();`, please change it like this `Resources res;'. And keep same code in onCreate